# Material UI + Nextjs: can't resolve '@/theme' module

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui

I'm a MUI beginner and I'm having an issue with the `material-ui-nextjs` [app router example](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/tree/master/examples/material-ui-nextjs) - I've set up the project, but am getting an error when importing the `theme` module - "Module not found: Can't resolve '@/theme'". Here are relevant snippets of my code in `layout.js` (in line with the project example code) and image of my dir structure.

```
import theme from '@/theme';

//...

<AppRouterCacheProvider options={{ enableCssLayer: true }}>
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    {/* CssBaseline kickstart an elegant, consistent, and simple baseline to build upon. */}
    <CssBaseline />

//...

  </ThemeProvider>
</AppRouterCacheProvider>
```

[dir structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Mosa.png)

I've checked the alias in `jsconfig.json`and location of `theme.js`, both are correct. Restarting the dev server / Reinstalling dependencies makes no difference. Any pointers would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be with the way you’re importing the theme module in your layout.js file. The @ symbol in the import statement is often used to represent the src directory, but this depends on the configuration of your project.

```
import theme from '../theme';
```

Or, if you want to use the @ alias, you need to configure it manually. You can use the module-alias package or configure it in the jsconfig.json or tsconfig.json file (if you’re using JavaScript or TypeScript respectively).

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried both of these previously, without luck, `../theme` produced an error, though a different one, but now works, though I'm not sure why. Thanks for the suggestion :)